# Search query: grouping and merging multiple searches

Tags: entries, search

Is it possible to 'group' search logic in the `craft.entries.search` query? I need to do the following: `[a OR b OR c]  AND  [d OR e]  AND  [x OR y OR z]`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine `OR`s within the same column but you can't easily combine multiple columns with an `OR` statement.

```
craft.entries.yourFieldHandle('OR, x, y, z').anotherFieldHandle('OR, d, e')
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Robin, that answers my question. I also emailed Craft support – posting Brad's response below for posterity, which suggests other ways to approach this.

> Robin is correct here: [Search query: grouping and merging multiple searches](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/24195/search-query-grouping-and-merging-multiple-searches)
>
> If you're looking for more complex, you might be able to pull it off with a plugin that listened to the onBuildElementsQuery event (https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/events-reference#elements-onBuildElementsQuery) or possibly through an external search service like Algolia. There's a Craft integration for the latter here: https://transition.topshelfcraft.com/software/craft/searchplus/overview

Thanks again

Gavin